# Wget: http request sent, awaiting response.... 400 bad request

Tags: wget, bad-request

I was trying to download list of files from a text file using wget and save them in a folder (here "game" is folder name), earlier it was working fine but all of sudden it stopped working means wget is not downloading any files from the given list.

Command:

```
wget --no-check-certificate -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off -Pgame \ -i ./list.txt
```

Contents of list.txt

```
http://html5.gamedistribution.com/9c9aa954aa8a4b838958d10656677a16/images/menu_parlante-sheet0.png
http://html5.gamedistribution.com/9c9aa954aa8a4b838958d10656677a16/images/btnpausa-sheet0.png
http://html5.gamedistribution.com/9c9aa954aa8a4b838958d10656677a16/images/btnpausa-sheet1.png
http://html5.gamedistribution.com/9c9aa954aa8a4b838958d10656677a16/images/bgscoreui-sheet0.png
http://html5.gamedistribution.com/9c9aa954aa8a4b838958d10656677a16/images/btnback-sheet0.png
http://html5.gamedistribution.com/9c9aa954aa8a4b838958d10656677a16/images/btnback-sheet1.png
http://html5.gamedistribution.com/9c9aa954aa8a4b838958d10656677a16/images/bgcredits-sheet0.png
http://html5.gamedistribution.com/9c9aa954aa8a4b838958d10656677a16/images/titulo-sheet0.png
```

If the list contains only 1 line/ file address/path then wget downloading the file if it consists of multiple lines of urls then its giving error as **"http request sent, awaiting response.... 400 bad request"**

Comment: Why in the world other application has caused this error I dont know, yesterday I had installed few apps, After removing them now everything is working fine, thanks for your time & reply

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me (without the backslash), the first four links return 404 response though:

```
wget --no-check-certificate -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off -Pgame  -i ./list.txt
```

Comment: No still same error
Resolving html5.gamedistribution.com (html5.gamedistribution.com)... 104.25.172.105, 104.25.171.105
Connecting to html5.gamedistribution.com (html5.gamedistribution.com)|104.25.172.105|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2018-04-07 01:55:35 ERROR 400: Bad Request.

Converted 0 files in 0 seconds.